# Is it a poor practice to use all caps for class names in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, naming-conventions

Consider a class for Foo ID's:

```
class Fid
```

This isn't a good name because it obscures the meaning.

```
class FID
```

This is better because it means Foo IDs.

Most classes in Ruby are CamelCase, so is it a bad practice to use all caps?

What about JSON class?

Comment: There are class names in Ruby that are exactly like this.  Abbreviations are obscure, by definition, as in "not clear".  So why not use `FooIdentification`  It is clear, you can store it in a shorter name if you would like, in the context of your program.

Of course, it isn't unclear if your program has a name that gives context to the abbreviation.

Comment: Because it is an application ID similar to a DB ID. `Identification` doesn't really mean anything in the context the app. `FIdentifier` is better, but `ID` is a common name that encapsulates the meaning.

Comment: @vgoff makes a good point, but some shortish abbreviations, like `FooID` are perfectly clear, and long names, like `FooIdentifacation`, are easy to misspell.  (Of course, some short names, like "guerdon" are also easy to misspell.)

Comment: Misspelling in programs are not uncommon, but I would venture to say that a consistently misspelled name is not such a problem.  Also, tab completion helps with consistently spelling long names.  If something is then found to be misspelled, you can fully correct it, without changing the behavior of the program.  And I would venture to say that any n+1 length word is just as simple to misspell as any other, it only requires a change in 1 character.

Comment: `FID` or `Fid` suggest, more or less, that it's F's ids not Foo's. I suggest using Cary Swoveland's `FooID`. I am not sure how this works with the gems so I would use `FooId`. I guess you should check a gem's guide if you want to create gem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Ruby style guide on https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide , you should:

> Use CamelCase for classes and modules. (Keep acronyms like HTTP, RFC,
>   XML uppercase.)

The ID part should be all uppercase. But I'm not sure why you want to shorten the Foo. The best solution would be to use something like FooID.

JSON is all caps because it's an abbreviation.